# TypeError: bbox_iou() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x1y1x2y2' in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, object-detection, yolov5, pruning

```
    Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   obj_loss   cls_loss  Instances       Size
  0%|          | 0/203 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 691, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 580, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device, callbacks)
  File "train.py", line 343, in train
    loss, loss_items = compute_loss(pred, targets.to(device))  # loss scaled by batch_size
  File "/root/All Projects/yolov5KD1st/utils/loss.py", line 215, in __call__
    iou = bbox_iou(pbox.T, tbox[i], x1y1x2y2=False, CIoU=True)  # iou(prediction, target)
TypeError: bbox_iou() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x1y1x2y2'
wandb: Waiting for W&B process to finish... (failed 1). Press Control-C to abort syncing.
wandb:  View run swept-glitter-8 at: https://wandb.ai/my-research-project/YOLOv5/runs/2x6b5tqs
wandb: Synced 6 W&B file(s), 0 media file(s), 0 artifact file(s) and 0 other file(s)
wandb: Find logs at: ./wandb/run-20230509_024133-2x6b5tqs/logs
```

The above is error show when I try to run yolov5 model below is screen shot which show this error in details .if anyone has idea please help.
[image]
The above error as for lines refered are below.
[image]

```
 # Forward
            with torch.cuda.amp.autocast(amp):
                pred = model(imgs)  # forward
                #Introduction of Teacher Model
                if opt.distill:
                    with torch.no_grad():
                        t_pred = t_model(imgs)
                        loss, loss_items = compute_loss(pred, targets.to(device))  # loss scaled by batch_size
                # distillation
                if opt.distill:
                    dloss = compute_distillation_output_loss(
                        pred, t_pred, model, opt.dist_loss, opt.temperature)
                else:
                    dloss = 0
                loss += dloss
                loss_items[-1] = loss
                # loss, loss_items = compute_loss(pred, targets.to(device))  # loss scaled by batch_size
                #above statement used by default line 352
                # End of Teacher Model
                if RANK != -1:
                    loss *= WORLD_SIZE  # gradient averaged between devices in DDP mode
                if opt.quad:
                    loss *= 4.

            # Backward
```

Below is how i was running my model.

```
** python train.py --weights weights/yolov5m.pt \
        --cfg models/yolov5m.yaml --data data/VisDrone.yaml --epochs 100 \
        --batch-size 32  --hyp data/hyps/hyp.scratch-med.yaml **
```

**below is the link to code on github**

https://github.com/ashymuzuro/yolov5-pure-kd

As to what I expect is for the model to run instead of showing errors.

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.